# Maven Local Repo not used by eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have a problem regarding maven and , I guess, eclipse.
I need to import an external jar in my maven project but could make it to work.

I followed this procedure:

1. Create a local-maven-repo folder at the root level of the project
2. Added the repository in the pom.xml of the project

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>local-maven-repo</id> 
    <url>file://${project.basedir}/local-maven-repo</url> 
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

3. Deployed the jar from command line using this command (terminal at root of the project)

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=it.info01 -DartifactId=fatturazioneColombia -Dversion=1.0 -Durl=file:./local-maven-repo/ -DrepositoryId=local-maven-repo -DupdateReleaseInfo=true -Dfile=./lib/fatturazioneColombia.jar
```

4. Structure gets created and looks like this in eclipse
   [Eclipse structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkEBo.png)
5. Added dependency in pom.xml like this

```
<dependency>   
<groupId>it.info01</groupId>
<artifactId>fatturazioneColombia</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version> 
</dependency>
```

Eclipse does not see the dependency and it looks like it is looking at it only in the default .m2 repository

```
The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library /Users/a.zabaroni/.m2/repository/it/info01/fatturazioneColombia/1.0/fatturazioneColombia-1.0.jar
```

Any help ? I tried to work with settings.xml file in maven but that is not my cup of tea.
Thanks

EDIT:
Thanks for the answer and yes by myself in the meantime I did not use maven deploy but maven install

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install-file  -Dfile=./lib/fatturazioneColombia.jar -DgroupId=it.info01  -DartifactId=fatturazioneColombia -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

and it works (repo create in .../.m2/etc)
But if I add

```
-DlocalRepositoryPath=file:./local-maven-repo/
```

the repo is created but STILL not used. I saw on eclipse configuration for local repo but It looks to me that I can have only one local repo. How can I specify two

Comment: This is not the right procedure. The correct procedure is much simpler: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4955635/6505250

Comment: @howlger your response might be wrong, dependency provided as scope system might be required while deploy, build jar or much more problems.

Comment: @Alessandro Zabaroni try make new property with absolute path - the fastest way
If you need to have relative path then let me know

Comment: @KamilKrzywański I linked to a question, not to the answer you seem to be talking about.

Comment: @howlger Thanks. In the meantime I did that by myself. It works but if I specify in the command a local repo, it is created but eclipse does not use that, even if in pom.xml

Comment: Right-click on the project and choose _Maven > Update Project..._ in order to fetch the dependency from the repository you refer in your `pom.xml` in the `<repositories>` element to the Maven local repository that is by default in your user directory in `.m2/repository` (Maven uses a local repository to which all required dependencies and plugins are downloaded, independent of whether they come from a remote or other local Maven repository, like your `<id>local-maven-repo</id>`; if needed, this can be changed in the preferences _Maven > User Settings_).

Comment: I guess the simplest solution to your problem would be following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4955695/6505250) and removing `<repositories>` from your `pom.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough information to try and get the right solution, but I could you suggest you an alternative method.

Instead of a local repo you could use:

```xml
<dependency>   
  <groupId>it.info01</groupId>
  <artifactId>fatturazioneColombia</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version> 
  <system>file://${project.basedir}/local-maven-repo/fatturazioneColombia-1.0.jar</system>
</dependency>
```

**NB:** adjust on by yourself the artifcat path.